# Object Required Error from Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page, I have two radio buttons and a table.. if one of the radio buttons is checked it should make the table visible if the other one is checked invisible.. but this line is giving me a "JS Object Required". I am firing this from code behind .cs.. it fires fine but then i get that error.

```
 document.getElementById('tblnewpackinglogo').style.display = '';
```

See code below

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage() {
        var rdoImg = document.getElementById("<%=radImage.ClientID%>");
        if (rdoCurrImage2.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('tblnewpackinglogo').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('tblnewpackinglogo').style.display = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

TABLES

```
   <table id="tblImage" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" runat="server"
    visible="true">
         <tr>
             <td>
               <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" />
             </td>
          <td>
    <div class="FieldStyle">
           Select an Option</div>
                     &nbsp;
         <asp:RadioButton ID="radImage" 
              Text="Keep Current Image" 
              runat="server" 
              GroupName="LogoImage"
              OnCheckedChanged="radImage_CheckedChanged" 
              Checked="True" />

         <asp:RadioButton ID="radNewImage" 
              Text="Upload New Image" runat="server" 
              GroupName="LogoImage"
              OnCheckedChanged="radNewImage_CheckedChanged" />
         </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
           &nbsp;
             </td>
           </tr>
     </table>
     <table id="tblnewpackinglogo" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
      runat="server" style="display:none;">
           <tr>
           <td style="height: 41px">
                  <div class="Style">
                        Select a Logo Image</div>
                <div class="ValueStyle">
                     <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadImage" 
                          runat="server" 
                          Width="300px" />
                             </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably that you need to get the name-mangled `ClientID` of the table:

```
document.getElementById('<%= tblnewpackinglogo.ClientID %>').style.display = '';
```

You're already doing it with the radio button above.

Also, if you're injecting the script from the code-behind file, then you'll still need to use the `ClientID`, as the JavaScript will run on client-side.

Comment: Let me test, actually this might be the case, my tables have a runat=server

Answer (score 0):

That error means that something of the form `(null or undefined expression).someproperty` is occurring. Naturally there is no `someproperty` on `null`/`undefined`. For the line:

```
document.getElementById('tblnewpackinglogo').style.display = '';
```

It is most likely that the problem is `getElementById` is returning `undefined` which would be caused if there was no element with the id `tblnewpackinglogo` *at the time* it was invoked.

Since there is a `tblnewpackinglogo` then -- unless FishBasketGordo's answer is correct -- I suspect the issue may be that `ShowImage` is invoked before the DOM has been loaded. Either that or there is another trivial error that does not align with the above post.

Inspect the *actual HTML* to see what is generated and use a tool like FireBug to try `getElementById` manually. Both FireBug and MS Script Debugger also offer more detailed debugging support to inspect the state at the time of the exception.

Happy coding.